# Was the Bride previously married to Bill?

Tags: plot-explanation, kill-bill

Bill is wearing a wedding ring during the whole *Kill Bill* movie. Is that supposed to mean he was married with the Bride in the first place?

Comment: How do you know it’s a wedding ring?

Answer (score 2):

No, it's pretty explicitly [explained in the movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Bride_(Kill_Bill)#Kill_Bill_Vol._1) that Bill and Beatrix were not involved, although she was pregnant with his baby.  They never do explain or even hint at who her future husband was.  Knowing Tarantino, it was probably Seth Gecko.  ;o)